# finding $T_n=S_1+S_2+...+S_n$ when $S_n=(2n-1)+(2n+1)+(2n+3)+...+(4n-1)+(4n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any elegant way to find the sum:

$T_n=S_1+S_2+...+S_n$ when

$S_n=(2n-1)+(2n+1)+(2n+3)+...+(4n-1)+(4n+1)$

**without** using the fact that $1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?

$S_n$ is an arithmetic series.

Thanks

Comment: Could you better explain the terms of the sum? I have no idea what the $...$ terms actually are.

Comment: @Axoren - i edited the question.

Comment: My question still holds. In the definition of $S_n$, there is an ellipsis ($...$) accounting for excluded terms. However, it's not clear what those terms would be if they weren't excluded.

Comment: ok it remains the same as the previous pattern.

Comment: What is the previous pattern? It is not clear. There is no obvious pattern that arises from $\{-1, 1, 3, ... -1, 1\}$ nor $\{2, 2, 2, ... 4, 4\}$. Is the sum $S_n$ a specific classification of sum, which the name of would help significantly?

Comment: @Axoren i think it's kind of clear that $d=2$. anyway i checked and that's the meaning.

Comment: @Axoren: $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (2n-1+2k)$

Comment: Until it was mentioned that it was an arithmetic series, it wasn't clear.

Comment: you are right, it could be different things.

Comment: @ali: It seems like you can't really get away from using or deriving the  sum-of-squares formula you mentioned because you'll definitely be able to derive a form of it from the formula for $T_n$ by looking at $T_{n}-T_{n-1}$

Comment: yes i didn't see how to do so as well.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $S_n$ is just a finite arithmetic series; it has first term $2n-1$, last term $4n+1$, and altogether $\frac12\big((4n+1)-(2n-3)\big)=n+2$ terms, so

$$S_n=\frac{(n+2)\big(2n-1)+(4n+1)\big)}2=3n(n+2)\;.$$

Now a little [finite calculus](http://notes.komputerwiz.net:8000/w/images/1/11/Gleich_2005_-_Finite_Calculus.pdf) [PDF] takes care of the rest:

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^nS_n&=3\sum_{k=1}^nk(k+1)+3\sum_{k=1}^nk\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}3k^{\underline 2}+\frac32n(n+1)\\\\
&=\left[k^{\underline 3}\right]_1^{n+2}+\frac32n(n+1)\\\\
&=(n+2)^{\underline 3}+\frac32n(n+1)\\\\
&=n(n+1)(n+2)+\frac32n(n+1)\\\\
&=\frac12n(n+1)(2n+7)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks, it's hard to understand without the steps but ill try to read the PDF.

Comment: @ali: You’re welcome. Finite calculus is pretty neat; there’s also a good treatment of it in Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*.

Comment: thanks a lot that's very cool:) +1

Comment: @ali: You’re very welcome.